# Laravel 5.1 - Date Validation & Attribute casting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

My model has the following validation and rules :

```
public $rules = [
    'hire_date'     => 'date|required|required_with:dismiss_date',
     OR
    'hire_date'     => 'date_format:"Y-m-d"...',
];

protected $casts = [
    //'hire_date'     => 'date' ,
    'dismiss_date'    => 'date' ,
];

// Or 

protected $dates = [ 
    'hire_date'   
];
```

If I cast the Hire Date or any other date field then it Throws an exception, as if the validation is not checking the format ; `e.g 2017-08-AA`

> A two digit hour could not be found Data missing" on line 582 of
>   .....nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php

If I remove the attribute casting for dates the validation works as expected and throws a validation exception. A workaround to keep the casting was to use mutators for all date fields

```
public function setHireDateAttribute ( $date )
{
    $this->attributes['hire_date']   =   TZ::isValidateDate($date) ? $date : null;
}
```

So my question is there something wrong with the setup ? if not what is the point of the `date` or `date_format` validations if I have to do it manually.

Comment: What's with the `OR`s? Which are you using and which is giving you the error? And I don't believe you need to use `$casts` for dates. Just use the `$dates` array.

Comment: by `OR` I mean i tried both combinations, I agree I can just ignore the `$cast` but I need to retrieve the dates as Carbon instances instead of defining ‎accessors as well. I tried the `$dates` array but same results. Why is the validation not playing well ? I read somewhere to use `$dates` only for datetime and cast is better ( link : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/dates-vs-casts )

Comment: If your attribute is defined in `$dates`, it is returned as a `Carbon` instance, unless you override the accessor.

Comment: I understand, assume `protected $dates = [  'hire_date'  ];` and my rules as above `date` or `date_format|Y-m-d`, no casting besides `$dates`, no mutators and if I try to submit let's say `2017-08-AA` I get the carbon exception not the validation. Now, I remove `protected $dates`, submit same input, I get the validation error as expected.. Maybe I shouldn't use both.. not sure

Comment: If you're submitting this `2017-08-AA`, `Carbon` is going to choke on it, because it's not a valid date. How or where are you running these validations? It sounds like you're populating and getting the data from your model, by which time the invalid date has already been passed to `Carbon`.

Comment: Im just seeding random data, using the UI as well. I was looking a way to validate user input with the validator, so if I understand correctly a submitted date ( casted ) will be passed to Carbon before the validation ? shouldn't the validator check the string or input format first ?

Comment: No. Post ALL of your code, where you create your validator, get your data, etc. If you're talking about `$dates`, you're using a model. And at the moment you're passing invalid data to your model and then trying to validate it. That's not going to work.